# How to remember username/password when calling tf.exe?

Tags: command-line, passwords, remember-me

I use tf.exe command to get the latest codes but it keeps asking for username/password - is there a way to make those credentials remembered?

I've looked at the tf.exe argument list but no options allowing to pass-in username/password. What can I try next?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you need is adding the parameter **/login**, i.e. `/login:DOMAIN\Username,YourPassword`, to your `TF.exe` command.

Example:
`TF.exe get $/Path/To/Source/On/TFSServer /recursive /login:DOMAIN\Username,YourPassword`

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you define an environment variable named TF_AUTO_SAVE_CREDENTIALS, then you only need to provide login credentials once per session. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190725.aspx

Comment: Where can I get the domain name? I'm using VS Online.

Answer (score 7):

You can store the credentials in the Stored Windows Credentials.

See http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/05/21/Automatically-connect-to-TFS-under-another-user-account.aspx for more information

Comment: Thank you Hofman! Though, I'm looking for a parameter syntax.